# Integrate SCORM In PHP YII Framework With PHP Version 5.4

Tags: php, yii, yii2, scorm

I Am Working On YII Framework In Which I Have To Integrate SCORM, And I Am Not Able To Understand That What Will Be The Best Way To Get This Done, I Am Totally New To SCORM I Have No Idea About SCORM.

I Had Search For Many Option Like(Moodle, Chamilo, ILIAS) But All Are Not Compactable

How I Integrate It?
What Should I Use?

My PHP Version Is 5.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the kind of integration you need.

First you must know the SCORM standard with some detail. I suggest you surf to https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/ and try to get the "pieces" you need to work on with Yii .